# material-ui, angular: table inside a table

Tags: angular, material-ui

I have a table with four static headers and two static columns. The last two column data's were changing according to if condition. I have to make a table below into an angular material table.

the first table is a normal table.

the second table is the one i have created using material table.

i want the second table to be look same as first table

[image]

Comment: insert your code

Answer (score 0):

see that you can use colspan in a material table as another tables.

Imagine the example of material table with weigth and symbol. You can use some like

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 ....
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <ng-container *matCellDef="let element">
        <td mat-cell *ngIf="element.position%2"> {{element.weight}} </td>

        <!--see the "colspan="2"-->
        <td colspan="2" mat-cell *ngIf="element.position%2==0">

            <!--as ngTemplateOutlet, in outlet send an array with an unique element-->
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="subtabl; context: {$implicit: [element]}">
            </ng-container>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <ng-container *matCellDef="let element">

        <!--here we remove the cell in the oposited condition-->
        <td mat-cell *ngIf="element.position%2"> {{element.symbol}} </td>

    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
 ....
</table>

<!--I call the variable "datasource", that remember is an array with an unique element-->

<ng-template #subtabl let-datasource>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="datasource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="subcolumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: subcolumns"></tr>
    </table>
</ng-template>
```

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmzg9z?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)